# Find column names with unique constraints applied, for a table in Vertica database

Tags: vertica

In a Vertica database, I want to know the columns of a certain table, where the constraint "Unique" is applied.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE dim1 (    c1 INTEGER,
    c2 INTEGER,
    c3 INTEGER,
  UNIQUE (c1, c2)
);
```

I want to run a query where I enter the name of the table "dim1" and the result would be "c1,c2"

For more info regarding unique( Last line in the link) https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Constraints/UniqueConstraints.htm

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty easy to do by querying the system catalog, specifically [`V_CATALOG.CONSTRAINT_COLUMNS`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/CATALOG/CONSTRAINT_COLUMNS.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CVertica%2520System%2520Tables%7CV_CATALOG%2520Schema%7C_____5):

```
select column_name from V_CATALOG.CONSTRAINT_COLUMNS
where table_name = 'dim1' and constraint_type = 'u'
```